# correlations function gives an error: unused argument

Tags: r, function, correlation

As an assignment for an R programming class, I have to write a function that takes a directory of data files and a threshold for complete cases and calculates the correlation between two columns (sulfate and nitrate) from each file where the number of completely observed cases is greater than the threshold. The function should return a vector of correlations for the monitors that meet the threshold requirement

I am running R version 3.1.1 (via R studio) on MACOSX 10.9.5
this is my code

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
        filenames <- list.files(directory, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
        cors <- numeric()
        for (i in seq_along(filenames)) {
            tempDF <- read.csv(filenames[i])
                if(nrow(tempDF[complete.cases(tempDF),]) > threshold){
                j <- length(cors) + 1
                    cors[j] <- cor(tempDF$sulfate, tempDF$nitrate, use = "na.or.complete")
                        }    
        }
        return(cors)
}
```

the expected output for the code would look like:

```
cr <- corr("specdata", 150) 
head(cr) 
[1] -0.01895754 -0.14051254 -0.04389737 -0.06815956 -0.12350667 -0.07588814
```

however when I run cr on my code I get the error:

```
Error in cor(tempDF$sulfate, tempDF$nitrate, use = "na.or.complete") : unused argument (use = "na.or.complete")
```

I have tried various work arounds with to no avail. substituting `na.or.complete` for `na.rm` or `complete.cases` gives the same error. some advice would be really appreciated!
running args(cor) outputs: function (directory, threshold = 0) NULL

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `args(cor)`? My guess is you have redefined `cor` unintentionally.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  In addition to Thomas' suggestion, please post your OS, & R version.

Comment: thanks for the input I included the info in the edit

Comment: `rm(cor)` and try again. you named `corr` `cor` on an earlier attempt

Comment: I suspect you are using a different `cor` function (from a different package). What does `environment(cor)` return? For most of us it is : `<environment: namespace:stats>`

Comment: following previous comments. if you actually redefined the cor() funtion, typing in environment(cor) shall return <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

Comment: if I call environment(cor), it indeed returns <environment: R_GlobalEnv>. So I guess that somehow, I redefined cor. the question is how do I get it back to its original function?

Comment: Thanks everyone, you were right. I did redefine cor. exactly as rawr indicated in a previous iteration of the function I named it cor instead of corr and that caused the problem. now to finish rest of assignment

Answer (score 2):

There is no parameter named `na.rm` in function cor. You should substitute your code as:

```
use = "complete.obs"
```